# integrating $\ln(ax)$ in an equation.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The derivative $\frac{d}{dx}\ln{(ax)} = \frac{1}{x}$

What follows is that $\int{\frac{d}{dx}\ln{(ax)}} = \int{\frac{1}{x}}$

And so, $\ln{(ax)} + c_1 = \ln{|x|} + c_2$ where $a, c_1, c_2 \in\mathbb{R}$

In other words $a, c_1, c_2$ are arbitrary constants that, if we differentiate both sides, won't effect out final result. So, since these values are arbitrary constants, we can select $c_1 = c_2$ and $a$ to be non-zero, i.e. $3$ for lack of a better number.

But then  $\ln{(5x)} = \ln{|x|}$, which is clearly not true.

To me the reasoning seems ok, but the result seems absurd, any hints?

Comment: The thing is, you can't choose your arbitrary constants to meet the restriction $c_1=c_2$

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for:

$$\ln{|5x|} = \ln{|x|} + C$$

This is a correct equation. You cannot choose your arbitrary constants. The crux of the issue is that the end equation is determined up to one constant.

Comment: no, the constants cancel? Surely we can select $c_1 = c_2$

Comment: Think of arbitrary meaning "we don't immediately know what they are" rather than "we can choose them to be whatever we want them to be"

Comment: but d/dx(x+c) = 1 for any x, so we can choose an arbitrary c

Comment: You cannot use the derivative to prove that two functions are equal. You can only use it to prove that two functions are equal up to a constant. In this case, $\ln|x|$ and $\ln |5x|$ are equal up to a constant but not equal in general.

Comment: I just realised that, other wise we could make every number equal every other number

Comment: You may be getting confused with grouping of constants. If $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary then their sum is also arbitrary so we can replace them with $C = c_1 - c_2$ or whatever is convenient for your equation.

Answer (score 1):

You need the 2 functions to be equal,if their derivatives are equal it means that they change values with same rate,or that $f(x)-g(x)=c$, $\ln(ax)-\ln|x|=\ln(\frac{ax}{|x|})=\ln(\pm a)$.The constants are there since many functions have the same derivative but differ in a constant.Also arbitrary means that they can be equal to any value depending on the equation